# Javascript arrow function with the this reserved word

Tags: javascript, function, expression, this, arrow-functions

I am trying to make a function and later attach it to an existing object.
these are my objects:

```
const cake1 = new Obj('cake1','cake','vanilla');
const cake2 = new Obj('cake2','cake','chocolate');
const cake3 = new Obj('cake3','cake','vanilla');
```

Right now they don't have any methods.

These are my functions and data:

```
const flavors = ['vanilla','chocolate'];
const isChocolate = (cake , flavors) => {
  console.log(cake);
    if(typeof cake === 'object' && typeof cake.type !== 'undefined' && cake.type === 'cake'){
      if(typeof cake.meta !== 'undefined'){
         if(cake.meta === flavors[1]){//Chocolate
           return true;
         }
      }
    }
    return false;//Any other case
}

const checkTheCake =(flavors,isChocolate) => {
  if(isChocolate( this , flavors)) {  // this refer to window
    console.log('is chocolate');
  }else{
    console.log('is vanilla');
  }
}
```

And at last, I added the `checkTheCake` function as a method.

```
cake1.checkTheCake = checkTheCake;
cake2.checkTheCake = checkTheCake;
cake3.checkTheCake = checkTheCake;

cake1.checkTheCake(flavors, isChocolate);
cake2.checkTheCake(flavors, isChocolate);
cake3.checkTheCake(flavors, isChocolate);
```

At first when I ran that code `this` within `checkTheCake` referred to the window object. 
And when I changed `checkTheCake` from expression to statement I managed to solve the problem and it referred to my cake object.

```
function checkTheCake (flavors,isChocolate){
  if(isChocolate( this , flavors)){ //this refers to cake
    console.log('is chocolate');
  }else{
    console.log('is vanilla');
  }
}
```

My question is why javascript behave like this in that particular case.

After edit: at first, I thought the problem is about the function statement and function expression but it actually relates to the Arrow function.

Comment: The issue isn't whether you used a function expression or not. It about whether your function expression uses an arrow function. (A simple comment like this upon closing a question as a duplicate can go a long way toward helping users understand what's going on.)

Comment: yes, now I see that `const checkTheCake = function(flavors,isChocolate)`act the same way and it is about the arrow function indeed.